# Copy Column over, delete original column using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on simplifying a script, I wanted to create a script that would copy within a range of columns over to the furthest left unoccupied column. Then delete the original column.

I've tweaked this script I found to do mostly what I wanted, it copies everything over, but doesn't delete.

I also need it to make it so that it can choose which row in said column range to look at for reference.

Could someone take a look at the script and help finish what I've started? I've been learning Excel VBA slowly, and my work has caused me to jump ahead in multiple directions before I have been ready, so I know that the copy and delete options should be simple, but because of the my line of work, I haven't had the time to learn everything correctly, so sorry if this is a simple answer, but I need to keep this script as lean as possible, and this is what I've come up with so far with what I know and scoured the internet for code and help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveColumns()

    Dim cel As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cel In Intersect(.UsedRange, .[B:N]).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells
            cel = cel.Offset(0, 1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am kind of confused as to what exactly are you trying? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure... Here is the excel workbook.  Basically what I want to do is go down to row 6, then column B, then all the way to N, and any place there is a space, take the closest right column, copy the data to the left most empty column and delete the original data, and continue through till there are no more columns to move over. 

here is the link to the book http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/DeleteColumn.xlsm

Comment: So basically you want to delete cells I5:K193? and then repeat the same process for M5:M193? Also What about the data in rows 194 onwards?

Comment: don't mind the data under the main, I have a script that will get rid of it, so when this script runs it will run with nothing under it. In the case I want to move Copy G:G to F:F, then Delete G:G, move H:H to G:G, delete H:H, and continue till all the columns are side by side, with no space inbetween and no duplicates anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > don't mind the data under the main, I have a script that will get rid of it, so when this script runs it will run with nothing under it. In the case I want to move Copy G:G to F:F, then Delete G:G, move H:H to G:G, delete H:H, and continue till all the columns are side by side, with no space inbetween and no duplicates anywhere else.

What you want is complicated way of moving things. The easiest way is to delete the blank column. The rest of the columns will automatically move to the left :) I am assuming that there is no data after row 194.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Long, i As Long
    Dim DelRange As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("BackOrder")

    With ws
        lastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Column

        For i = 1 To lastCol
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(i)) = 0 Then
                If DelRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set DelRange = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, .Columns(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: The problem is that there is something on O and P which need to stay on O and P, what you are doing is moving the columns...which is something that can't be done in this situation.

Comment: With a slight change even that can be taken care of :) I will update the code when I wake up. Going off to bed :) it is already 5:45 AM